# getSelectedItem/Index for JComboBox not updating

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

For an assignment I am trying to create a Fantasy Football app; and I am trying to change the formation based on what is selected in the JComboBox. However, which ever selection I make, it is always stuck on the first index and will not update to a newer selection no matter what I do.

I have two classes, Fantasy, and Dropdown (ActionListener for JComboBox), and since it is stated that I need to use two separate classes, I cannot merge them in to a single class.

```
public class Fantasy extends JFrame
    {   
        String[] formationoptions = {"Select Formation", "4-4-2", "4-3-3", "3-5-2", "5-3-2", "3-4-3", "4-5-1"};
        JComboBox<String> formation = new JComboBox<String>(formationoptions);

        public Fantasy()
        {
            super("Fantasy Football");

            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.setSize(400, 600);
            this.add(formation, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            formation.setSize(400, 25);
            this.setVisible(true);

            formation.addActionListener(new Dropdown((String) formation.getSelectedItem()));
        }
    }
```

**Dropdown.java**

```
    public class Dropdown implements ActionListener
    {
        public String selected;
        public String a = "Select Formation";
        public String b = "4-4-2"; 
        public String c = "4-3-3";
        public String d = "3-5-2";
        public String e = "5-3-2"; 
        public String f = "3-4-3";
        public String g = "4-5-1";

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if (selected.equals(a))
            {
                System.out.println(a);
            }
            if (selected.equals(b))
            {
                System.out.println(b);
            }
            if (selected.equals(c))
            {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
            if (selected.equals(d))
            {
                System.out.println(d);
            }
            if (selected.equals(e))
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            if (selected.equals(f))
            {
                System.out.println(f);
            }
            if (selected.equals(g))
            {
                System.out.println(g);
            }
        }

        public Dropdown(String selected)
        {
            this.selected = selected;
        }
```

Currently the Dropdown class is not complete, and it is set to print the formation for testing, but no matter what I do, I only get "Select Formation" printed for any selection that I make.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 1):

So, rather then printing `selected` which never changes, you need to inspect the `JComboBox` itself and ask it what the selected value is...

```
public class Dropdown implements ActionListener {

    public String selected;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        System.out.println(cb.getSelectedItem());
    }

    public Dropdown(String selected) {
        this.selected = selected;

    }
}
```

You could then, update the `selected` value to the value which is actually selected by the `JComboBox`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `ItemListener`.

```
formation.addItemListener(new Dropdown());
```

and change class definition of `Dropdown` by this

```
public class Dropdown implements ItemListener {
    public String a = "Select Formation";
    public String b = "4-4-2"; 
    public String c = "4-3-3";
    public String d = "3-5-2";
    public String e = "5-3-2"; 
    public String f = "3-4-3";
    public String g = "4-5-1";

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
           String selected = ((JComboBox)e.getSource())
                               .getSelectedItem().toString();
           System.out.println(selected);
           // write here if else ladder or switch case
        }
    }
}
```

It'll work.

**UPDATE**

This can be achieved by `ActionListener` too. I listed here some differences in `ActionListener` and `ItemListener`.

> **`ActionListener`**
>
> - `ActionListener` gets called when you change the element in combo box even when element is same as previous.
> - Using action listener `actionPerformed` method is called just once when you change the element.
>
> **`ItemListener`**
>
> - `ItemListener` gets called when you change the element in combo box and it is not same as previous.
> - When you use `ItemListener`, `itemStateChanged` method is called twice, so you have to check the condition `if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {`, otherwise the method executed twice when you select new element.

Comment: Why would an `ItemListener` be better than an `ActionListener`? Do you really need to know when the selected item changes in the popup? Basically all you've done is exactly what an `ActionListener` would do without the need to check the reason for the event

Comment: Oooh, I like comparions, nice

Comment: If you didn't add first comment..I would have never checked for the difference..so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line of code into your program so that the jComboBox selection refreshes each time that section of code runs. This way you'll always get the current jComboBox value selected currently:

```
jComboBox.setName("");
```

For example, insert it like so in your code:

```
public Dropdown(String selected)
    {
        this.selected = selected;
        jComboBoxcb.setName("");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You never update the value of `selected` in response the the ComboBox changing.

Comment: How do I update the value of selected? I did not run into the problem when they were in the same class, but only started happening when I separated them.